# Why Chrome apps/windows do not follow GTK theme?

Tags: google-chrome, themes, gtk

I use Linux but at a noob level. Usually Most of the time I use Ubuntu based distros.

My browser of choice is Google Chrome.

Services as Netflix, Tweetdeck, etc., I use them as "apps" opened in their own window, but I don't know why, they do follow entirely the GTK theme.

Netflix Chrome App:
[image: Netflix Chrome App]

On the image you can see the fonts on the window title bar are in black and the window borders are in a light color.

Google Chrome:
[image: Google Chrome]

Google Chrome looks ok as the rest of my system: dark themed and light colored fonts.

As anyone any idea why this happens and if there is any way to fix it?